# MIN function doesn't work correctly in a SQL complicated query

Tags: sql, sql-server

The task is to select the sub category with the minimum profit per year.
The next query, selects few sub categories per year:

```
select 
  min (Profit), 
  CalendarYear, 
  EnglishProductSubcategoryName
from (
  select 
    SUM(fis.SalesAmount-fis.TotalProductCost) Profit, 
    t.CalendarYear, 
    sc.EnglishProductSubCategoryName
    from FactInternetSales fis 
    inner join DimProduct p 
            on fis.ProductKey = p.ProductKey
    inner join DimProductSubcategory sc 
            on p.ProductSubcategoryKey = sc.ProductSubcategoryKey
    inner join DimTime t 
            on fis.DueDateKey = t.TimeKey
    group by CalendarYear, EnglishProductSubcategoryName) aa 
    --Order by CalendarYear
) aa
group by CalendarYear, EnglishProductSubcategoryName
order by CalendarYear
```

Comment: Please explain what is the problem with the query you posted? how the `MIN` function doesn't work correctly? not the desired output? any errors?

Comment: The query selects for example - 2011, 20,000, gloves next line: 2011, 9,000, boots etc... There must be only one minimum category profit for each year.

Comment: The way you wrote this query, you'll get **one MIN() value per year and category** - so one for (2011, Gloves) and another for (2011, Boots) etc. - that's the way you wrote the query, that's the way you're getting your data.

Comment: So, I need to select one category for year... how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the category with the minimum profit for a given year, you need to rewrite your query:

```
select 
    Profit,
    CalendarYear, 
    EnglishProductSubcategoryName
from 
    (..... ) aa
where
    CalendarYear = 2011
    AND Profit = (SELECT MIN(Profit) FROM aa WHERE aa.CalendarYear = 2011)
```

This will find the row(s) - it could be multiple - that have the minimum profit (for 2011) as reported back by the subquery.

**Update:** since you need the minimum profit for every year, I would probably totally rewrite this query to something like:

```
;WITH YearlyProfitsByCategory AS
(
   SELECT
      SUM(fis.SalesAmount - fis.TotalProductCost) Profit, 
      t.CalendarYear, 
      sc.EnglishProductSubCategoryName
   FROM
      dbo.FactInternetSales fis 
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.DimProduct p ON fis.ProductKey = p.ProductKey
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.DimProductSubcategory sc ON p.ProductSubcategoryKey = sc.ProductSubcategoryKey
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.DimTime t ON fis.DueDateKey = t.TimeKey
   GROUP BY
      t.CalendarYear, 
      sc.EnglishProductSubCategoryName
),
YearlyMinProfits AS 
(
    SELECT
       CalendarYear, 
       EnglishProductSubCategoryName,
       Profit,
       RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CalendarYear ORDER BY Profit)
    FROM YearlyProfitsByCategory 
)
SELECT 
   CalendarYear, EnglishProductSubCategoryName, Profit
FROM YearlyMinProfits
WHERE RowNum = 1  -- the row with the smallest profit, for every year
```

This uses a CTE (Common Table Expression) and the `ROW_NUMBER()` ranking function - both available in SQL Server **2005** and newer (you didn't mention your version in your question)

Comment: The query must be dynamic... 2011 was just an example there can be 2011, 2012, 2009, years in the same table.

Comment: If the tables contains 2008, 2010, 2011, and 2012 years, the result must contain 4 lines. line for each year...

Comment: You don't need the statement *termination* character (`;`) at the *beginning* of the statement. It should go at the end (that's why it's called "termination character"). And it's a good habit to adapt the SQL standard style in SQL Server as well. See for example here: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons and here http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/post/yet-another-semicolon-rule-in-sql-server-denali.aspx

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: true - but more often than not, I (or someone else) forgets that .... better safe and sorry !